# can an array be used in place of individual column names in SQLite database?

Tags: android, database, arrays, sqlite

i have an SQLite database table with 93 columns

is it possible to create SQLite columns as an array or ArrayList?

instead of typing out each line as A0, A1,... on to A93,

create as array like this

```
private static final String[] AList;
```

i understand that it is possible to instantiate each element by using an array and for loop to assign a String value for each "A" column from A0 to A99,

however it looks like impossible to do the actual creation of the variables A0 to A99 themselves by using for loop and array

any ideas?

sample of the code used

```
public class DatabasePrototype {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database";
public static final String SMALL_TANK_CHECK_RESULT = "small_tank_check_result";
public static final String LARGE_TANK_CHECK_RESULT = "large_tank_check_result";

public static final String CLEAN_TANK_RESULT = "clean_tank_result";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String _ID = "_id";

// variables for LARGE_TANK_CHECK_RESULT
public static final String A0 = "a0";
public static final String A1 = "a1";
public static final String A2 = "a2";
public static final String A3 = "a3";
public static final String A4 = "a4";
public static final String A5 = "a5";
public static final String A6 = "a6";
public static final String A7 = "a7";
public static final String A8 = "a8";
public static final String A9 = "a9";... on to 93 as last variable

 private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE1 =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + LARGE_TANK_CHECK_RESULT + " (" + _ID +      " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  
        A0 + " TEXT, " + A1 + " TEXT, " + A2 + " TEXT, " + A3 + " TEXT, " +A4 + " TEXT, " + A5 + " TEXT, " +A6 + " TEXT, " +
        A7 + " TEXT, " + A8 + " TEXT, " + A9 + " TEXT, " + A10 + " TEXT, " + A11 + " TEXT, " + A12 + " TEXT, " +A13 + " TEXT, " +
        A14 + " TEXT, " + A15 + " TEXT, " + A16 + " TEXT, " + A17 + " TEXT, " +A18 + " TEXT, " + A19 + " TEXT, " +A20 + " TEXT, " +
        A21 + " TEXT, " + A22 + " TEXT, " + A23 + " TEXT, " + A24 + " TEXT, " +A25 + " TEXT, " + A26 + " TEXT, " +A27 + " TEXT, " +
        A28 + " TEXT, " + A29 + " TEXT, " + A30 + " TEXT, " + A31 + " TEXT, " +A32 + " TEXT, " + A33 + " TEXT, " +A34 + " TEXT, " +
        A35 + " TEXT, " + A36 + " TEXT, " + A37 + " TEXT, " + A38 + " TEXT, " +A39 + " TEXT, " + A40 + " TEXT, " +A41 + " TEXT, " +
        A42 + " TEXT, " + A43 + " TEXT, " + A44 + " TEXT, " + A45 + " TEXT, " +A46 + " TEXT, " + A47 + " TEXT, " +A48 + " TEXT, " +
        A49 + " TEXT, " + A50 + " TEXT, " + A51 + " TEXT, " + A52 + " TEXT, " +A53 + " TEXT, " + A54 + " TEXT, " +A55 + " TEXT, " +
        A56 + " TEXT, " + A57 + " TEXT, " + A58 + " TEXT, " + A59 + " TEXT, " +A60 + " TEXT, " + A61 + " TEXT, " +A62 + " TEXT, " +
        A63 + " TEXT, " + A64 + " TEXT, " + A65 + " TEXT, " + A66 + " TEXT, " +A67 + " TEXT, " + A68 + " TEXT, " +A69 + " TEXT, " +
        A70 + " TEXT, " + A71 + " TEXT, " + A72 + " TEXT, " + A73 + " TEXT, " +A74 + " TEXT, " + A75 + " TEXT, " +A76 + " TEXT, " +
        A77 + " TEXT, " + A78 + " TEXT, " + A79 + " TEXT, " + A80 + " TEXT, " +A81 + " TEXT, " + A82 + " TEXT, " +A83 + " TEXT, " +
        A84 + " TEXT, " + A85 + " TEXT, " + A86 + " TEXT, " + A87 + " TEXT, " +A88 + " TEXT, " + A89 + " TEXT, " +A90 + " TEXT, " +
        A91 + " TEXT, " + A92 + " TEXT, " + A93);";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to even think about array, that means your database schema is improper for your task.

Correct solution is to [normalize your schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In your case it may mean creating slave table that would store your `A1`, `A2`, ... fields each as one row and link back to master table record.

Doing so has following advantages:

1. You can support arbitrary number of your original `An` values - it could be 0, it could be 1000.
2. Slave table will be quickly searchable (provided you create appropriate indexes).
3. Your schema would be more future-proof - much less likely to be in need of modifying.
4. Your queries will be much simpler and shorter, however they will be joins for 2 tables, not 1 as it is now.

Comment: fantastic answer, thank you for sending me in the right direction